# Sencha touch suitable document.ready type function

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In Jquery theres a function

```
$(document).ready(function (){..}
```

Is there such a thing in Sencha Touch 2?

I'm aware of

```
Ext.Setup({ onReady: function () {...} })
```

However I can only call `Ext.Setup` once. If I have multiple views how would I take care of this? I would like a function to load when a view is loaded. Do I have to this via a controller? Can I use a snippet of code injected into the index.html (The platform is built on node and requires this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your controller that requires the view just add an init: function() { //do something }, extjs will take care of the rest... usually if your trying to call a function that requires the view to be loaded, then add the 'painted' listener to your view and it will be called when the view is rendered